# Using task scheduler for scheduling job in C#

Tags: c#, job-scheduling

i am using following code for scheduling task in c#

```
  TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        DateTime t = ts.RootFolder.Tasks["Test"].LastRunTime;
        td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

        td.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
        //td.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(23);

        td.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger
        {
            StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
            DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Friday
        });
```

i want to add week days more than one...

I found that i can do this by using

```
DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday | DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday
         | DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday | DaysOfTheWeek.Friday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday
```

But the problem is that i want to do this dynamically. User will choose on week days and then i will set... pls help how to do this.

Comment: do you have a system admin that can just setup the scheduled task for you..? why would you let the user select or choose what day(s) to run the task.. what about overlapping have you thought about that as well?

Comment: its an application for database conversion which user want to auto start batch processing on a particular time period

Comment: cool I was just wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a list of integer with user selections

Then you could do

```
foreach (int day in days) 
{
    td.DaysOfWeek |= (DaysOfTheWeek)day;
}
```